# big javascript function document.write renders in 1 sec in firefox and 4min in chrome, with html code

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, dom

Chrome takes 4 minutes to render a page with a big javascript function and Firefox takes like 1-2 sec.

It's simple code, a `document.write` javascript function that has been called around 30 times so it would not have to download 30 x 1mb of dropdown data. Firefox renders it in 1 second and chrome in 4 minutes.

Here is the live html link: html link was removed Check it in Firefox and check in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function writeHTMLasJS_product_type(){
document.write("<option value=\"4\">ITEM 1<\/option>");
document.write("<option value=\"5\">ITEM 2<\/option>");
document.write("<option value=\"144\">Item 3<\/option>");
document.write("<option value=\"145\">Item 4<\/option>");
document.write("<option value=\"146\">Item 5<\/option>");
}
writeHTMLasJS_product_type();
```

now its like 1mb of data, with like 20 writeHTMLasJS_product_type(); functions

It's not about processor or memory because I have 5ghz i7 with 48gb ram... It's either a Google Chrome limitation, that can be overridden, or javascript that can be customized in better way to do the same thing, what do you think?

//I was thinking that some of you will be interested to see the difference between amount of time that Chrome needs to render this out even if you don't know the answer what's happening here. So please don't jump to voting the question down just because you don't know the answer.

Best Regards

Comment: you should edit the question adding the guilty code snippet, along with the right amount of context (not too little, but not everything either).

Comment: the person that clicked on the provided html link can see it when click on + Prikaži komplete (like 30 dropdowns created with that fucntion)

Answer (score 2):

> The enemy of the DOM, which is document.write(), ... then I've got to
>   do all this extra work, 'cause you're a jerk. **[document.write() is a jerk](http://youtu.be/WxmcDoAxdoY?t=9m36s)** [image: external link].

[Paul Irish on document.write()](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxmcDoAxdoY&feature=youtu.be&t=9m27s) [image: external link]

Long story short: don't use `document.write()`. Period. Watch more of the video to find out why. Basically it messes up your browser's parsing process. And, apparently, Chrome has more trouble with the (enormous!) amount of `document.write()`'s you're using than Firefox. But the real problem is not Chrome handling `document.write()`'s too slow but you using `document.write()` for no-good reason.

Why not manipulate the DOM directly? Put the data in a variable / some variables (possibly using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and maybe even a single or a few [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls but that's not required) and set all the data using DOM manipulation methods.

I don't intend to lay it down step-by-step but stuff like this:

```
function writeHTMLasJS_product_type(){
    document.write("<option value=\"0\">IZABERITE GRUPU<\/option>");
    document.write("<option value=\"4\">DSLR<\/option>");
    document.write("<option value=\"5\">PROSUMER<\/option>");
    document.write("<option value=\"6\">KOMPAKTNI<\/option>");
    document.write("<option value=\"8\">MiniDV KAMERE - VIDEO ZAPIS NA KASETU<\/option>");
    //...4000-or-so more lines
}
```

Should be something like:

```
var items = { 
    0: "IZABERITE GRUPU",
    4: "DSLR",
    5: "PROSUMER",
    6: "KOMPAKTNI",
    8: "MiniDV KAMERE - VIDEO ZAPIS NA KASETU",
}
```

Which, by itself, already saves up **a lot** of bandwidth. Next you simply use DOM manipulation to iterate the items and add them to your dropdowns/textboxes/whatever-the-hell-it's-supposed-to-do.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMpvF/) [image: external link] demonstrating the basic idea.

If you insist on using `document.write()` (which, again, **I highly advise against**!) then at least try to keep the number of calls to `document.write()` to a minimum:

```
document.write(
      '<option value="0">IZABERITE GRUPU<\/option>'
    + '<option value="4">DSLR<\/option>'
    + '<option value="5">PROSUMER<\/option>'
    + '<option value="6">KOMPAKTNI<\/option>'
    + '<option value="8">MiniDV KAMERE - VIDEO ZAPIS NA KASETU<\/option>');
```

Not to be a jerk myself (as opposed to `document.write()` [image]): We don't live in the '90s anymore; brush up on your techniques / knowledge and get with the rest of us in 2013!

Comment: I know all about that, dont get me wrong, but still:
1. firefox does it in like 1 sec
2. it saves like tones of bandwidth

Comment: How would it save bandwidth? I don't see that; in fact: it only increases bandwidth since you're adding "document.write(...)" all-over the place?

Comment: i doc.write in javascript function and than repeated js call to that function so it does saves a lot of bandwidth when big js is called like 30 times to render (like when renders model that html page)

Comment: and Robill thanks for that youtube video it really showed me how much my programming skills from like 10 year ago has aged now, perhaps I will tell my old client witch site I still maintain from time to time that he have to use firefox till chrome speeds things up or I find time to learn html5 if there is no fast implementing solution ahead

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5; my answer works equally well with HTML4 and `document.write()` causes the same trouble in HTML5 as in HTML4. If I were you I wouldn't hold my breath for Chrome (Google) to fix this; it may well be never fixed. Oh, and my name is not `Robill` but `RobIII`, roman numeral III ;)

Comment: I tried to minimize document.write so they are not repeated all the time but rendering in chrome was still the same

Comment: sorry RobIII:) I will check in to the var thing soon

Comment: How can I make this more clear than what I've already reiterated 15 times? **Do *NOT* use `document.write()` *AT ALL*!**. Just stop it. Step back. Brush up your technique/knowledge and in a day or 2 you'll be good to go. It ain't rocket science to use a little DOM manipulation (possibly even helped by jQuery or similar frameworks) and a little JSON.

Comment: I had to leave (go home from work) but now I'm home and I took another look at your form. Again, I'm trying very hard not to sound like a jerk, but your form is horrible as well; it is a *really* bad interface and the [UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design) is very bad too. I would really like to urge you (and suggest) that you take a step back from the project and take a look at "modern" UI's and techniques.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://youtu.be/Il4swGfTOSM?t=21m57s) too (which I happened to stumble upon today) which also highly advises against `document.write`

Comment: HTML5's parser has support for document.write. It's pretty close to the date, so probably it's you who is not up-to-date :) Apart from that, all DOM manipulation can slow things down unless you know how to deal with that which requires internal knowledge of browsers and this  requires you to follow browser development which is not something everybody can cope with. Just saying. :)

Comment: HTML5 supporting document.write doesn't imply you need to (ab)use it in this fashion. I know my HTML5 very well, thank you. Apart from that; I never claimed that other types of DOM manipulation don't slow things down; I was pointing out that (user) "day" was using the worst possible inefficient method. The link has been edited-out but go have a look at [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15839171/revisions) and see for yourself. I also didn't imply to follow up on browser development but to keep up on **webdevelopment**. Stop pointing out stuff I didn't say. Just saying :)